# Treat url as c# object so I can split params

Tags: c#, http

I want to use a console application to easily divide a URL from its params so I can URL encode the parameters. Is there a type that makes this simple?  Please keep in mind that this is being run outside of a web server.

The URL is of the form

E.G.

```
string url = "http://sitename/folder1/someweb.dll?RetrieveTestByDateTime?PatientID=1234&param2=blah blah blah";
```

So then I can do

```
string finalUrl = "http://sitename/folder1/someweb.dll?RetriveTestByDateTime?PatientID=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(PatientIDValue) + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(param2Value);
```

Second, is the second `?` valid? This data comes from a 3rd party app.  Surely this can be accomplished with Regex, but I prefer not to use it as most people on my team do not know regular expressions.

Comment: You could write your own utility.

Comment: The second `?` on the URL would be treated as part of the name of the first parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class - pass in the string `url` to the constructor and it will parse out the different parts.

The query will be in the `Query` property and you can reconstruct the URL easily using the `Scheme`, `AbsolutePath` and the encoded `Query`.

Comment: I think Uri can't solve OPs problem (or may be I misunderstood his problem).

Comment: @SaeedAmiri - I believe this is exactly what the OP is asking for.

Comment: You totally misunderstood the question and did not provide any help to solve this issue at all

Comment: Oded - This answer is even better than what I hoped for.  The Uri object automatically encoded the URL!  So I don't even need the utility.  Very nice!

Comment: @Trikks - Seeing as the OP accepted the answer, it looks like it helped him. Please explain how I misunderstood the question.

Comment: He asked to change inner parameter values of the querystring. The Uri class simply chunks the url into pieces. Thats half of the solution. Describe how you can change the value as described in the question with your code.

Comment: @Trikks - `return new Uri("the url").AbsoluteUri;`

Comment: Removed the downvote, please post the code on how you implemented this Brian. Can't really see how you can chain querystring parameters with this unless if you hardcode.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your url structure is bad

```
string url = "http://sitename/folder1/someweb.dll?RetrieveTestByDateTime?PatientID=1234&param2=blah blah blah";
```

should be

```
string url = "http://sitename/folder1/someweb.dll?RetrieveTestByDateTime&PatientID=1234&param2=blah blah blah";
```

A possible solution, I'm not in a development environment now so this is from the head. Some changes may need to be done to the code.

```
string url = "http://sitename/folder1/someweb.dll?RetrieveTestByDateTime&PatientID=1234&param2=blah blah blah";
var uri = new Uri(url);
var queryString = uri.Query;
NameValueCollection query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString)
query["PatientID"] = string.Concat(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(PatientIDValue), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(param2Value));

// Rebuild the querystring
queryString = "?" + 
                 string.Join("&", 
                              Array.ConvertAll(query.AllKeys, 
                                                key => string.Format("{0}={1}", 
                                                HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key), 
                                                HttpUtility.UrlEncode(query[key]))));
```

Comment: The URL is input from a 3rd party webservice.  It doesn't make much sense to change their URL (assuming it works).

Comment: The Uri class should fix this automatically, i think.